# Running a Javacript code on an HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, html

This is a ion exchange calculation for softener resin linked to my job.  I've run this code in Javacript and displayed it on the console but where do you begin to run that on a webpage. I know how to link a JS file using the script on a HTML page but how does the code get executed. I'm a bit confused with getELement ID or querySelectors so i was hoping to get some pointers of where i can start to look.  Apologies for the ametuer question

```
  const totalCapacity = function (resinVolume, hardness) {
  let exchange = 50;
  return (resinVolume * exchange) / hardness;
};

let softener = totalCapacity(50, 200);
console.log(softener + ' m3');
```

Comment: Generally if you load a JS file and load it in via the `<script>` tag it just runs the code inside that file. You can also use the `<script>` tag to paste the code directly inside your html file. Have a look here to learn how to implement some basic functionality https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Comment: Stackoverflow's intended use is to offer answers for very specific programming questions. That's why you will probably experience some downvotes on this post because noone here wants to write a tutorial for you. Don't be intimidated or discouraged to keep asking questions though!

Comment: Thnaks very much. I wanted to create a table evtually to run that code with an answer to be displayed by clicking a button but i'm struggling to find where to begin with it

Comment: You probably won't find a tutorial for the specific thing you wish to build but I'm sure any tutorial on JS basics will give you the knowledge you'll need to achieve this. Try to break down your problem into small parts that can be looked up easily for example "how to implement a clickable button".

Answer (score 1):

This is an immediately invoked function:

```
(const totalCapacity = function (resinVolume, hardness) {
  let exchange = 50;
  return (resinVolume * exchange) / hardness;
};
let softener = totalCapacity(50, 200);
console.log(softener + ' m3');)();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I've run this code in Javacript and displayed it on the console but where do you begin to run that on a webpage. I know how to link a JS file using the script on a HTML page but how does the code get executed.

If You put your JS code into a script tag it gets executed alongside HTML code. That's why most people put ther script tags at the very bottom of the `body` element. That is - to make sure all HTML elements are accessible at the moment their JS code gets executed.

This is the default behaviour. You can also tell the browser directly to run your code when the page loads by enclosing it into a function and using the `window` object.

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    console.log('The page has fully loaded');
});
```

> I'm a bit confused with getELement ID or querySelectors

That's exactly what I mean by accessible. You can select existing HTML elements, perform actions on them and attach listeners.

```
document.getElementById()
```

Refers to a situation where You want to access an HTML element that has it's own id. e.g.

```
<div id='container'></div>
```

Query selector is a lot more sophisticated tool used to access HTML elemnts. It allows You to use CSS selectors - at the very basic level You can do the same thing as above, by writing (CSS sytax, so id = #):

```
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
```

If You write:

```
const container = document.querySelector('div');
```

It will work too because selector searches for the first `<div>` element it sees and returns it. You can find all matching elements and get them in an array by calling `querySelectorAll()`

There is way more to learn if You need it, w3schools was always a good place to read about how HTML, CSS and JS work together.

Quick example:

```js
const totalCapacity = function (resinVolume, hardness) {
  let exchange = 50;
  return (resinVolume * exchange) / hardness;
};

const outputElement = document.getElementById('output');

const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  outputElement.textContent = totalCapacity(50, 200);
});
```

```css
h3 {
  color: green;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<button>Compute</button>
<h3 id='output'></h3>
```

In this case, stackoverflow makes sure to put code into right places but it might as well look like that on a single page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <style>
        h3 {
          color: green;
          font-size: 2em;
        }
    </style>

<body>
    <button>Compute</button>
    <h3 id='output'></h3>

    <script>
        const totalCapacity = function (resinVolume, hardness) {
          let exchange = 50;
          return (resinVolume * exchange) / hardness;
        };

        const outputElement = document.getElementById('output');

        const button = document.querySelector('button');

        button.addEventListener('click', function() {
            outputElement.textContent = totalCapacity(50, 200);
        });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

When You define variables and functions You can do it in global scope and local scope. This determines their lifetime in the browser environment. Global scope is basically not enclosing them with any brackets (functions etc), this makes declared variables and functions avaiable untill the enviornment gets destroyed on page reload.

In the code above You would have it as:
global:
`totalCapacity`, `outputElement`, `button`

local:
`resinVolume`, `hardness`, `exchange`

Btw. putting everyting into a single file is considered bad practice in larger projects but does well for short scripts and testing.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script language = "JavaScript">
  function multiply() {
    with(document.multiplication) {
      result.value=x.value * y.value;
    }
  }
</script>

<form name="multiplication">
  <input type="text" name="x" size="5">
  <input type="text" name="y" size="5">
  <input type="text" name="result" size="5"><br>
<input type="button" value="Multiply" onClick="multiply()">
```

You can get some idea from the above example.

Comment: [**Warning**: Use of the `with` statement is not recommended, as it may be the source of confusing bugs and compatibility issues. See the "Ambiguity Contra" paragraph in the "Description" section below for details.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)

Comment: I was only giving him someone idea, like how js works in html. I too know about the cons with working with "with".

Comment: Note also, that `with` has been deprecated and is marked as legacy in the [lastest EcmaScript standard - ES2022](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations.html#sec-with-statement)